# How to store large json array

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I currently have a large data set being produced by my system. It looks something like this:

```
[
 {
 "OrderId": "1",
 "A":, "value1A",
 "B":, "value1B"
 },
 {
 "OrderId": "2",
 "A":, "value2A",
 "B":, "value2B"
 }
]
```

It's really a pretty simple list, but it is very large, and goes well over the 2MB size limitation for a single document. What's the best practice for sharding/chaining all of these orders so that it is easy to query them as one related list?

Is there something built in to handle this? Or must I modify the schema and add some sort of tracking ID to each order and store each one as their own document?

Comment: Hi, does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best practice for sharding/chaining all of these orders so
>   that it is easy to query them as one related list?

It's all about data structures.When our documents are larger than the document DB `2MB` limit, we have to consider splitting the documents. If you have a clear classification rule for these orders, then I strongly recommend that you split these `Orders` and add the partition key to them.

For example:

```
{
 "Type" : "AAA", 
"OrderId": "1",
 "A":, "value1A",
 "B":, "value1B"
 },
 {
 "Type" : "AAA",
 "OrderId": "2",
 "A":, "value2A",
 "B":, "value2B"
 },
{
"Type" : "BBB",
 "OrderId": "1",
 "A":, "value1A",
 "B":, "value1B"
 },
 {
"Type" : "BBB",
 "OrderId": "2",
 "A":, "value2A",
 "B":, "value2B"
 }
```

So that you could retrieve them conveniently based on the partition key.

Don't worry about the change of the data schema, you can use [Cosmos DB Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) for bulk export and import data of document db.

Hope it helps you.